# Ошибка Future provider Error: Could not find the correct Provider<List<MyStart>> above this ListStarts Widget

Tags: flutter

Впервые использую provider и не знаю как исправить эту ошибку. У меня есть bottom nav bar, в котором я перехожу на другие страницы и когда я перехожу на страницу, где использую future provide то выдает эту ошибку:

Error: Could not find the correct Provider<List> above this ListStarts Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that ListStarts is under your MultiProvider/Provider<List>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

Класс с provide:

```
class MyStartsProvider {
  final String _dataPath = "assets/MyStarts.json";
  late List<MyStart> myStarts;

  Future<String> loadAsset() async {
    return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () async {
      return await rootBundle.loadString(_dataPath);
    });
  }

  Future<List<MyStart>> loadMyStart() async {
    var dataString = await loadAsset();
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMyStartData = jsonDecode(dataString);
    myStarts = MyStartList.fromJson(jsonMyStartData['MyStarts']).myStarts;
    print('done loading starts');
    return myStarts;
  }
}
```

myApp:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      //debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MultiProvider(providers: [
        FutureProvider(
          create: (BuildContext context) async =>
              MyStartsProvider().loadMyStart(),
          initialData: [],
        ),
      ], child: BottomNavigator()),
    );
  }
}
```

Где и как я использую provide:

```
class ListStarts extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<MyStart> starts = Provider.of<List<MyStart>>(context);
    return ListView.separated(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        separatorBuilder: (context, int index) => Divider(
              height: 56,
            ),
        itemCount: 3,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            width: 327,
            height: 343,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Column(
    ....
```

Comment: Надо бы `typedef MyStartList = List<MyStart>;` и далее повсеместно использовать этот тип. Я не уверен что решит проблему, но это как минимум более читаемо и правильно :) Ну и тогда будет желательно классу виджета `ListStarts` дать более внятное имя, чтобы не путаться (чем плох наиболее естественный вариант `Starts`? Это же виджет, а не экземпляр типа `List`, в конце концов).

Comment: Есть подозрение что проблему решит `FutureProvider<MyStartList>` (или `FutureProvider<List<MyStart>>` если без введения типа). Сейчас видимо `Future<dynamic>` в списке providers, да? (посмотри в тултипе, если твой редактор кода поддерживает вычисление типов).

Comment: @yar85 Первый комментарий учел, спасибо. По второму: тип показывает **FutureProvider<List<dynamic>>**. 
Сорян, что могу показаться тупым, просто в мобилке, как и со флаттером недавно, если я правильно понял, то  вместо **FutureProvider** в main мне надо было написать так **FutureProvider<List<MyStart>>** и если так сделать, то выдает другую ошибку

Comment: _«`FutureProvider<List<MyStart>>` и если так сделать, то выдает другую ошибку»_ - а какую именно ошибку, предлагается угадать?))

Comment: @yar85 извините, интернет временами умирает
**The following assertion was thrown building Container(constraints: BoxConstraints(w=327.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity), margin: EdgeInsets(36.0, 175.0, 26.0, 0.0)):
dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedProviderScope<List<MyStart>>>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _StartsState.initState() completed.**

Одним сообщением не помещается, отправлю еще вторым

Comment: @yar85 
**When an inherited widget changes, for example if the value of Theme.of() changes, its dependent widgets are rebuilt. If the dependent widget's reference to the inherited widget is in a constructor or an initState() method, then the rebuilt dependent widget will not reflect the changes in the inherited widget.
Typically references to inherited widgets should occur in widget build() methods. Alternatively, initialization based on inherited widgets can be placed in the didChangeDependencies method, which is called after initState and whenever the dependencies change thereafter.**

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127198/discussion-between-yar85-and-steind-vy).

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена следующими правками:

- Изменение типа результата метода `loadMyStart` на `Future<MyStartList>`. Класс `MyStartList` объявлен так:

  ```
  class MyStartList {
    final List<MyStart> items;
    MyStartList(this.items);

    MyStartList.fromJson(List<dynamic> myStartsJson)
        : this.items = myStartsJson.map((myStart) => MyStart.fromJson(myStart)).toList();
  }
  ```
- Соответственно изменен и тип свойства `myStarts` провайдера

  ```
  class MyStartsProvider {
    final String _dataPath = "assets/MyStarts.json";
    late MyStartList myStarts;
    /*....*/
  }
  ```
- Изменение типа провайдера в `MultiProvider`

  ```
  MaterialApp(
    home: MultiProvider(providers: [
      FutureProvider<MyStartList>(
        create: (BuildContext context) async => MyStartsProvider().loadMyStart(),
        initialData: MyStartList([]),
      ),
    ],
    /*....*/
  )
  ```
- Использование `Consumer<MyStartList>` вместо `Provider.of<List<MyStart>>`

  ```
  class ListStarts extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Consumer<MyStartList>(
        builder: (context, startList, child) =>  ListView.separated(/*....*/)
      ),
    }
  }
  ```
- Соотв. изменение выражения чтения значения в виджете вложенном в консьюмер

  ```
  Text('${startList.items[index].title}', /*....*/)
  ```